# Include assets fonts from rollup bundled reactjs lib in npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, fonts, rollup

I'm trying to bundle a reactjs library with rollup to create a npm package with all my UI components but I'm finding a problem with the font icons.
When I try to use an icon from an other react app I receive:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://<my-url>/Flaticon.woff2
```

It seems it is searching the fonts inside the root folder of the new app and not inside the node_modules/my-lib directory which indeed contains the font files.

This is my rollup config file:

```
export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      name: 'my-lib',
      exports: 'named',
      globals: { react: 'React' }
    }
  ],
  external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    postcss({
      inject: true,
      config: {
        path: './postcss.config.js',
      },
      sourceMap: true,
      extract: false,
    }),
    copy({
       {
          src: [
            'src/assets/icons/Flaticons/Flaticon.woff',
            'src/assets/icons/Flaticons/Flaticon.woff2',
            'src/assets/icons/Flaticons/Flaticon.ttf',
          ],
          dest: 'build',
        },
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you get this working in the end?

Answer (score 0):

try add for cjs and esm something like this:

```
copy({
        targets: [
          { src: 'src/assets/icons', dest: 'dist/esm/assets' },
          { src: 'src/assets/icons', dest: 'dist/cjs/assets' },
        ],
      }),
```